# not getting last Password change time on AIX by default lsuser command

Tags: unix, aix

I need all attributes for all users from AIX system for this I am using 
*"lsuser -f ALL command"* this gives me all attributes but not giving **lastupdate** attribute which used to indicate last password change dateTime of user.
for getting **lastupdate** attribute I have to execute one more command
*lsuser -a lastupdate ALL* .

Is there any way or configuration to get **lastupdate** in default lsuser command like all other attributes???
(It seems like lsuser not reading etc/security/passwd file byDefault)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `lastupdate` field is stored in a file that is (should be) readable **only** by the root user, so you will need to use sudo or some other privilege escalation method to run `lsuser`. Note this section of the [lsuser man page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds3/lsuser.htm), with my emphasis in bold:

> Access Control: This command must be a general user program with execute (x) access for all users. Since the attributes are read with the access rights of the user who starts the command, **some users might not be able to access all the information**. This command must have the trusted computing base attribute.

Sample /etc/security directory permissions:

```
drwxr-x---   11 root     security      11378 Nov 13 19:40 /etc/security
```

Sample /etc/security/passwd file permissions:

```
-rw-r-----    1 root     security     19664 Nov 14 12:54 /etc/security/passwd
```

Sample /etc/security/passwd contents (showing the `lastupdate` field):

```
user:
        password = O/jxmbjWeafOfyUw
        lastupdate = 1510064402
```

Further reading:

- [Password expiry, on IBM.com](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-password_expiry/index.html)